# Fancybox 3 - specify buttons array from inline data-attr?

Tags: vue.js, fancybox

Can you specify what buttons you want from an inline implementation of Fancybox 3?

For example:

```
<a :data-src="someImage.jpg" 
    data-fancybox 
    data-fancybox-buttons="['zoom', 'share', 'download']"> // something like this?
  <img ... />
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use data-options:

`data-options='{"buttons": ["download", "share", "close"]}'`